# How to give an hyperlink to a label in Struts2?

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, hyperlink, label

While designing a web page with a form using Struts2 tags, I have a check box for 'terms and conditions'.

```xml
<s:checkbox name="agree" label="Agree terms & Conditions"/>
```

Now I want give a hyper link to the label *Agree terms and conditions*. How can I do that ?

Comment: I am not upset @DaveNewton. If some one is downvoting a question, they must have thought that _the question is a stupid question_. That means _they must have know the answer for it_. I am saying it's OK to 'down vote' the question, but you should write the answer for it so that _we will know the answer_ at least.

Comment: @Aadya There are many reasons people downvote, some valid, some not. Also, thinking a question is stupid doesn't mean they know the answer (or that there is an answer, etc.) My point is that *we*, e.g., the-people-being-voted-upon, have no say in who votes, how they vote, why they vote, etc. and spurious commentary beyond "Please explain the downvote" aren't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `simple` theme for that tag, that allows you to write the HTML by yourself. Then create the label as you wish (along with the table structure that [would have been created by the XHTML Theme](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html)):

```html
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
        <label for="agree" class="label">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1654265/">
                Agree terms & Conditions
            </a>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <s:checkbox id="agree" name="agree" theme="simple" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

This will result in the following HTML (the hidden field is generated by Struts for checkboxes):

```html
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
        <label for="agree">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1654265/">
                Agree terms & Conditions
            </a>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" />
        <input type="hidden"  id="__checkbox_agree" 
                            name="__checkbox_agree" value="true">
    </td>
</tr>
```

that should be what you need.

Comment: if i do like that the 'checkbox' in the result page is being displayed on top of the form instead of the place where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML that you get with `<s:checkbox     name="agree"            label="Agree terms & Conditions"/>`. The problem is probably related to the fact that the `XHTML` (default) Theme is generating also table/tr/td tags, that are missing here. Since I always use `SIMPLE` theme, I don't remember the exact html generated by the `XHTML` one, but after you'll post it, I'll be able to fix the answer

Comment: @Aadya have you read my comment ? Please copy here the HTML you see with "View Source"

Comment: It is too long to post here @AndreaLigios

Comment: I can see that this checkbox part is not being included in the table.

Comment: Please post only the relevant code produced by the s:checkbox tag (the <tr><td> around him, whatever)

Comment: Around that particular code there is no `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: Around the code generated by your *original* s:checkbox. Please, try putting `<!-- START --><s:checkbox name="agree" label="Agree terms & Conditions"/><!-- END -->` and post the generated HTML between start and end comments

Comment: Never mind, I've gone through the docs. Please try the new code and let me know

Comment: The link 'Agre...' is coming on top of the form(no `<tr>`) for it. One more 'Agre...' is coming at the end of the form with checkbox.

Comment: You have probably not put the theme="simple", haven't you ? BTW noone is forcing you to use Struts tags, you can copy and paste the generated HTML in my answer and use that. Please try and let me know